# Can't position "reader's cursor" at top of Java "help window" with scrollbar and more than screenful of text

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a "Help" button that, when clicked, opens a JFrame window and displays more than a screenful of lines of text that are read from a file. After the entire help file has been processed, only the middle of the file is shown in the window. The scrollbar is positioned at the middle of its range. Here's a simulated window that simulates showing lines 33 thru 52 of 80 lines in all:

[image]

**I want line 1 to be visible after the last line has been processed, without user having to scroll up.
How?** I looked throughout the methods and properties of the JFrame named Helpframe but none seem to apply.

Here's the relevant code from the 3 classes involved:

```
public class Help extends JFrame{

  static String [] lines = null;

  public     Help() { 

    lines = new String[]{
                     " ... blah blah blah blah ... ", ... } // 100 more strings follow
} // end of class Help

public class UserIO extends JFrame {  

  private void btnHelpMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    HelpOutput helpFrame = new HelpOutput();
    Help       help      = new Help();

    for (String line : Help.lines)
      helpFrame.appendOutput(" " + line);
```

***EDIT AND SOLUTION***

```
    HelpOutput.txaOutput.setCaretPosition(0);
```

***Added that line right after the `for`; problem solved.***

```
  } ...
} // end of class UserIO

public class HelpOutput extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    JTextArea txaOutput      = new JTextArea();
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txaOutput);
...
  public void appendOutput(String s){

    txaOutput.append(s + "\n");
  } ...    
} // end of class HelpOutput
```

I solved a similar problem in a different program by using `....selectAll()` to position the "reader's cursor" at the BOTTOM of the window in that situation, which was ideal, since the bottom line was a summary. But even if that method were available, I wouldn't want to do that with the current program.

Comment: I added just `HelpOutput.jScrollPane1.setAlignmentX(TOP_ALIGNMENT);` after the `for` statement and I added `jScrollPane1.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));` to the constructor for `HelpOutput`. Didn't help, didn't think it would.

Comment: And after Googling, I tried this--didn't help. 
`HelpOutput.jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
HelpOutput.txaOutput.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Added that after the `for` and problem solved.